# Exclude every library except one for proguard shrinking & obfuscation

Tags: android, proguard

Is there a way that `Proguard` would allow me to shrink only one of my dependencies and leave my app & other dependencies' files untouched?

The library that I want to shrink is `Guava`. I have the following in my `proguard-rules.pro`

```
-keep class !com.google.common.** { *; }
-keep enum !com.google.common.** { *; }
```

For now, the app works with those options, but I may have missed a scenario or two while testing. Is this the correct way to do it? Does this also retains attributes in the excluded classes?

P.S. - This is an open-source android application. Therefore I choosing not to obfuscate my code.